# Specify the path of a different buffer than the current one in an ex command?

Tags: ex-mode

I know I can use `:!echo %` to echo the name of a file in the current buffer.

What can I do if I want to do that for a different buffer that I have open?

Comment: See :help bufname() but it would be easier to help you if you told us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @romainl I'm trying to pass the filename/path of a different buffer from my currently selected buffer to an external command via ex.

Comment: That's how. I'm asking what for?

Comment: I dunno `echo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass name of buffer no. 1

```
:!echo Name of buffer 1 is #1:S
```

Read section 6 of `cmdline.txt` (`:h cmdline-special`).

However, in practice one usually ends up with something like that

```
:echo printf("echo %s", bufname(1)->shellescape())->system()
```

as restricting the whole expression only to cmdline-special/environment vars/backticks etc. might be inconvenient.